# Finding the number of vowels in a string

Tags: java, string

im really stuck on this problem for homework and i cant seem to get my code to work. I have to use the .indexOf() method and . subString() method, and it has to be able to count both caps and lowercase vowels. any if any help will be greatly appreciated i'm really stuck.

```
public class StringAnalyzer 
{
public static int numberOfVowels(String aWord)
{
    int num = 0;
    int length = aWord.length() -1;
    int index = 0;
    String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    while(index <= length)
    {
        aWord = aWord.substring(index, index +1);
        num++;
    }
    return num;
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    numberOfVowels("derp");

}

}
```

Comment: Why not use the `String#charAt(int)` method?

Comment: Part of your problem is that you are not incrementing your index in your while loop, so the loop won't ever end.

Comment: You also don't have any `indexOf()` in there. Nothing in your code checks if letters are vowels.

Comment: im only allowed to use the indexOf() method and the subString() method I cant use anything else :/

Comment: Use substring to get each char individually, then use indexOf to see if that char is inside your vowels string. I leave the code to you. That is the best way for you to learn these types of things.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static int numberOfVowels(String aWord) {
    int num = 0;
    final String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";

    for (int i = 0; i < aWord.length(); i++) {
      if (vowels.indexOf(aWord.substring(i, i+1)) != -1) {
        num++;
      }
    }

    return num;
}
```

Fits all the requirements, only uses substring and indexOf.

substring(i, i+1) gets the char at index i as a java.lang.String, and indexOf checks if the string with one character exists in the vowels string.